# After I upgraded Ambari version, I can't receive any email notifications

Tags: email, hadoop, notifications, ambari

I upgraded Ambari version 2.4.0

After that, I can't receive any email notifications when components are critical, ok, warning etc.

Following is what I do to find problem.

I stopped one of regionserver.

After that, I ran command

> curl --user admin:passwd http://myurl:8080/api/v1/cluster/{clustername}/alert_notices?fields=*

[results]

> { "href": myurl,
>       "items": [ ]
>     }

[ambari-server.log]

`23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,259  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AbstractResourceProvider:925 - Received a updateHostComponent request, clusterName=, serviceName=HDFS, componentName=DATANODE, hostname=, request={ clusterName=, serviceName=HDFS, componentName=DATANODE, hostname=, desiredState=STARTED, state=null, desiredStackId=null, staleConfig=null, adminState=null}
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,265  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: SQOOP
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,265  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: HDFS
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,265  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: MAPREDUCE2
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,265  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: OOZIE
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,265  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: TEZ
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,266  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: SPARK
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,266  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: HBASE
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,266  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: ZOOKEEPER
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,266  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: YARN
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,266  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: PIG
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,267  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: HIVE
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,267  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: SLIDER
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,267  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: AMBARI_METRICS
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,267  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2140 - Iterating service type Instance in createHostAction:: NIFI
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,282  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AmbariManagementControllerImpl:2329 - AmbariManagementControllerImpl.createHostAction: created ExecutionCommand for host , role DATANODE, roleCommand START, and command ID 897--1, with cluster-env tags version1479886775473
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,301  INFO [ambari-action-scheduler] ServiceComponentHostImpl:1067 - Host role transitioned to a new state, serviceComponentName=DATANODE, hostName=, oldState=INSTALLED, currentState=STARTING
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,441  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AbstractProviderModule:953 - Current Metrics collector Host : null
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,441  INFO [ambari-client-thread-102] AbstractProviderModule:958 - New Metrics collector Host : 
23 Nov 2016 16:58:00,951  INFO [qtp-ambari-agent-91] HeartBeatHandler:332 - HeartBeatHandler.sendCommands: sending ExecutionCommand for host , role DATANODE, roleCommand START, and command ID 897-0, task ID 7953
23 Nov 2016 16:58:06,679  INFO [ambari-heartbeat-processor-0] HeartbeatProcessor:505 - Updating applied config on service HDFS, component DATANODE, host 
23 Nov 2016 16:58:06,681  INFO [ambari-heartbeat-processor-0] ServiceComponentHostImpl:1067 - Host role transitioned to a new state, serviceComponentName=DATANODE, hostName=, oldState=STARTING, currentState=STARTED`

Also, I restarted ambari server several times, but I can't resolve it.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you check the ambari-server log ?